# Using OR operator with named groups

Tags: java, regex

In regular expression java we can use named groups like this `(?<group_name>pattern)`. Also it supports OR operator like this `(pattern1|pattern2)`. 
Can i use named groups and OR operator something like this `(pattern1)|(pattern2)`? That is if one pattern in group matches then result is true.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example string and `pattern1` / `pattern2`, or explain a bit how you want to use it. If I read your question correctly, you want something like `(?<pattern1>someRegex)|(?<pattern2>someRegex)`? But since you already know about named groups, and also know about `(pattern1)|(pattern2)`, I think I might misunderstood the purpose of your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "name" in [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you will find this:

> **Special constructs (named-capturing and non-capturing)**
>
> `(?<name>X)`  X, as a named-capturing group

So yes you can use named groups:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<foo>a)|(?<bar>b)").matcher("a");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("foo")); // a
    System.out.println(m.group("bar")); // null
}
```